# How to deploy newer version of library and new static code to all users?

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries

I currently have a spreadsheet template that is copied and renamed for each new client. The template contains its own code and html files. It also references a library. I do not have a good understanding of the deployment process.

I currently have a test and prod version of the library. I make changes to the test and then copy them to the prod when ready to publish to the company. I can always be sure that everyone is using the proper prod version.

This is not the same for the code and html resident with the named spreadsheet. This code is static from when the file was copied.

I want to be able to update the library and local code dynamically through the DEPLOY process. Is this achievable? Should the library code be "included" directly into the template rather than being "referenced"? (If yes, How?)

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation, free resources and more details. You maybe able to accomplish your task using [tag:google-apps-script-api]

Comment: I do not see how to add access to Googles Apps Script API. It does not come up in the list of accessible SERVICES when I am editing the code.

Comment: Try editing appscript.json

Comment: I added the suggested oauthScopes and still the Apps Script API is not one of the choices  for Services.

Comment: It won't be a "Advanced Google service". You need to use `Urlfetchapp` with `scriptapp.getOauthToken()` to access the api. Kindly ask a new question. It's  not clear what you're referring to.